# Is it worth to build a discharge circuit for long storage of lithium-ion batteries?

Tags: lithium-ion, zener, discharge, storage

I am making a battery powered system that might not be used for months. There will be an On-Off switch but I am planning to use a three position switch in order to discharge batteries to 3.9 V when it is planned to store them for long time, because, as far as I know, Li-ion batteries should not be stored fully charged for maximum battery life.

The circuit will look something like this:

[image: circuit]

Is it worth to add an extra button position? Will "4.2 V - 3.9 V = 0.3 V" really matter to increase battery life? Is this an applicable way to discharge batteries?